# Downloading Images on iPhone - How does Facebook do it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, image-gallery

How does the Facebook app go about downloading/displaying the images in photo galleries?  They appear to load in at varying times which would indicate some degree of threading?  Surely the app doesn't spawn X amount of threads (where X is the number of pictures) as this would cause performance issues?  Can anyone enlighten me as I would like to use something similar in my app (I will be regularly downloading a large amount of photos and displaying them in the app so downloading them one after another takes too long).  Also, these photos change on a fairly regular basis so downloading once and cacheing isn't really an option.

Is there some kind of framework/solution around that might help me achieve something similar to Facebooks galleries?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code the Facebook app uses to do this has been open-sourced as [the three20 library](http://three20.info/).  This functionality is provided in [TTPhotoViewController](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTPhotoViewController.m).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple. The images are downloaded asynchronously and have a reference back to where they are supposed to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use this Library, [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is like an extended version of the NSURLRequest. I have been using it to download images for later display, asynchronously. It has a nice CACHE implementation which saves bandwidth and loading times on your app.